# Calling a JS functions from another JS file in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js

I'm currently working in emberJS I need to call a function in the JS file which in the public/myjs.js from
app/components/mycomponent.js. It says could not find module named public/myjs.js

In app/component/mycomponent.js this is the following code I have:
`import functions from ../../public/myjs.js`

I have also tried this still not working:
`const functions = require("myjs");`

Thank you :)

Comment: Probably wrong path to the file

Comment: Bad bot. This does have sufficient details.

Answer (score 2):

files from the `public` folder can't be imported at the top of files (via normal `import X from Y`), they are separated from the build system.

the public folder is directly copied into your `dist` directory.

So a couple options to access `myjs.js`:

- use `await import('/myjs.js')` -- [native dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) will load the JS file from the public folder. make note of the leading slash here.
- move myjs.js to be within the `app` folder, and then `import X from 'my-app/myjs';`

Comment: Using `await import()` here has a bunch of caveats, so I wouldn't suggest it. You'll get no transpilation. And if you've otherwise enabled dynamic imports to be handled by the build system (which is the default in embroider and available with ember-auto-import), you'll need to convince those systems to leave your import() alone.